# Rails and Cocoon. Accessing values from child model in Edit Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I’m using Cocoon in a nested form where I have a model “Request” that can have many attachments (adjuntos), handled by Shrine.

The same form partial is being used both to Create and Edit the requests, and although the functionality is working fine and I am being able to upload the files and successfully update the models, I have a problem with the information shown for the Edit action.

The thing is that it is being rendered one input per each file currently attached to Request as expected and I can edit the attachment by selecting a new one or delete it, but I’m being unable to show the name of the file corresponding to each of these inputs, so the user won’t be able to know which of the attachments is editing. Apparently I can't use the object 'f' in _adjunto_fields.html.erb to access the values of the children model.

[image: this input corresponds to a currently attached file to this model]

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @request do |f| %> 
<%= render 'shared/errors', object: @request %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :ot %>
    <%= f.text_field :ot%>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :area %>
    <%= f.text_field :area%>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :titulo %>
    <%= f.text_field :titulo%>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :observaciones %>
    <%= f.text_field :observaciones%>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :prioridad %>
    <%= f.text_field :prioridad%>
  </div>

  <div id="adjuntos">
    <%= f.fields_for :adjuntos do |adjunto| %>
    <%= render 'adjunto_fields', f: adjunto %>
  <%end%>

  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'añadir adjunto', f , :adjuntos %>
  </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>
  <%end%>
```

`_adjuntos_fields.html.erb`

```
 <div class="nested-fields">
   <%= f.label :adjunto %>
   <%= f.file_field :adjunto%>

   <%= f.check_box :_destroy%>

   <%= link_to_remove_association "quitar adjunto", f %>
 </div>
```

Edit: Trying to access f.object in the form I get an error because f.object is nil:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :adjunto %>
  <%= f.file_field :adjunto%>
  <%#<%raise 'foo'%>
  <% parsed_data = JSON.parse f.object.adjunto_data %>
  <%= parsed_data["metadata"]["filename"]%>

  <%= f.check_box :_destroy%>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "quitar adjunto", f %>
</div>
```

`>> f.object
=> #<Adjunto id: nil, title: nil, adjunto_data: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, request_id: 1>`

But If I just uncomment raise 'error' debug mode I can actually access f.object from the console:

`>> f.object
=> #<Adjunto id: 4, title: nil, adjunto_data: "{\"id\":\"4cbf9b5477c586779069a5144cd67104.PNG\",\"stor...", created_at: "2017-09-26 20:49:47", updated_at: "2017-09-26 20:49:47", request_id: 1>`

Edit2. Calling the object outside from the _adjunto_fields form works:

```
<div id="adjuntos">
  <%= f.fields_for :adjuntos do |adjunto| %>
    <%= render 'adjunto_fields', f: adjunto %>
    <% parsed_data = JSON.parse adjunto.object.adjunto_data %>
    <%=parsed_data["metadata"]["filename"]%>
  <%end%>

  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'añadir adjunto', f , :adjuntos %>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you use <%= f.fields_for :adjuntos, @request.adjuntos do |adjunto| %> the result is the same?

Comment: If I try this then I get this error:   ``undefined method `_destroy' for #<Adjunto::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f5a32418a28>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how the object is being passed from the `fields_for` loop into the partial, but you should be able to access the adjunto object outside of the partial with `ajunto.object`, so you could add a line in `_form.html.erb` after rendering the partial (but still within the `fields_for` loop) to display the filename.

Answer (score 1):

To actually reach the object the form is handling, use `f.object`. So if, for instance, you want to show the original filename, you should do something like `<%=  f.object.adjunto.original_filename %>` and style it accordingly (wrap it in a label, a span, a hint?).

Comment: It is weird, writing f.object.adjunto_data in the form raises an error becaise f.object is nil although the attachment is still there    ``#<Adjunto id: nil, title: nil, adjunto_data: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, request_id: 1>``
>> But if I just raise an error, then I can actually access the object in the console: ``#<Adjunto id: 4, title: nil, adjunto_data: "{\"id\":\"4cbf9b5477c586779069a5144cd67104.PNG\",\"stor...", created_at: "2017-09-26 20:49:47", updated_at: "2017-09-26 20:49:47", request_id: 1>``